# Faceted Lattice Plots in R, e.g., wireframes: How to remove strips and add 1-Line subtitles

Tags: r, lattice

I use this kind of function (from iris data set)

```
model_test <- lm(Sepal.Length ~( Petal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Width +Species)^2,
data=iris)
gg<-expand.grid(Petal.Length=0:6,Species=levels(Species))
vv<-expand.grid(Sepal.Width=0:4,Petal.Width=1:4)

pd<-do.call(rbind,Map(function(Petal.Length,Species,Sepal.Width,Petal.Width){
              nd <- cbind(vv, Petal.Length=Petal.Length,Species=Species,
                               Sepal.Width=Sepal.Width, Petal.Width=Petal.Width)
              cbind(nd, pred=predict(model_test, nd, type="response"))},
              Petal.Length=iris$Petal.Length,Species=iris$Species,
               Sepal.Width=iris$Sepal.Width,Petal.Width=iris$Petal.Width))

wireframe(pred~Sepal.Width+Petal.Width|Species*Petal.Length,
           pd, drape=FALSE,scale=list(arrows=FALSE),subset=(Species=="setosa"),
           layout = c(3, 3))
```

I get this plot

[image]

**My Question(s)**:
If I include more factors in my model, the (coloured) strips would make the plots very small. How can I remove the green and light red strip and add a 1-Line Title
like `Species==setosa & Petal.Length==0`,...., `Species==setosa & Petal.Length==6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lattice is going to create a strip for each conditioning variable. If you want just one strip, try conditioning on the interaction. For example

```
wireframe(pred~Sepal.Width+Petal.Width|interaction(Species,Petal.Length),
           pd, drape=FALSE,scale=list(arrows=FALSE), subset=(Species=="setosa"), layout=c(3,3))
```

which gives

[image]

You can create the interaction ahead of time and customize the levels if you like with whatever description you want.

Comment: Wonderful easy solution!

Comment: You really shouldn't add new questions to an existing post. Ideally each question should have a singular focus. If you have a new question, you should open a new post.