# R: Lattice Plots/Wireframe : Splitting Panel Plots into single plots

Tags: r, lattice

How can I force wireframe panels to produce single plots instead of one panel plot/grid plot? The reason is that if I have to produce a Sweave/ Pdf File the original wireframe plot, which R produces and which you can see in my other post

[Faceted Lattice Plots in R, e.g., wireframes: How to remove strips and add 1-Line subtitles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055745/faceted-lattice-plots-in-r-i-e-wireframes-how-remove-stripes-and-add-1-line/30056035#30056035).

will look very small, especially if I have many many single wireframe plots. I can handle single plots more easily in Sweave.

Comment: In addition to the layout argument mentioned by @BondedDust, you can save the `"trellis"` objects produced by the **lattice**'s higher level plotting functions, and then plot selected elements of them. For example: `Depth <- equal.count(quakes$depth, number=8, overlap=.1); pp <- xyplot(lat ~ long | Depth, data = quakes); dim(pp); plot(pp[c(1,8)])`

Comment: Very interesting - learned today many new things. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lattice allows you to specify the number of columns and rows for the plots which then spill over onto adjacent pages if a multi-page device is used:

```
 pdf("nine.pdf", onefile=TRUE, paper="special")
 wireframe(pred~Sepal.Width+Petal.Width|interaction(Species,Petal.Length),
            pd, drape=FALSE,scale=list(arrows=FALSE), subset=(Species=="setosa"), 
           layout=c(1,1,9))
 dev.off()
```

On the console device they create new plots which stack up in the plot device and you can "scroll-back" with keystrokes that may vary depending on your unstated OS. The eps format is accessible using directions in `?ps`.